# Message bus: sender must wait for acknowledgements from multiple recipients

Tags: rabbitmq, message-bus

In our application the publisher creates a message and sends it to a topic.

It then needs to wait, when all of the topic's subscribers ack the message.

It does not appear, the message bus implementations can do this automatically. So we are leaning towards making each subscriber send their own new message for the client, when they are done.

Now, the client can receive all such messages and, when it got one from each destination, do whatever clean-ups it has to do. But what if the client (sender) crashes part way through the stream of acknowledgments? To handle such a misfortune, I need to (re)implement, what the buses already implement, on the client -- save the incoming acknowledgments until I get enough of them.

I don't believe, our needs are that esoteric -- how would you handle the situation, where the sender (publisher) must wait for confirmations from *multiple* recipients (subscribers)? Sort of like requesting (and awaiting) Return-Receipts from each subscriber to a mailing list...

We are using RabbitMQ, if it matters. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The functionality that you are looking for sounds like a messaging solution that can perform transactions across publishers and subscribers of a message. In The Java world, JMS specifies such transactions. One example of a JMS implementation is [HornetQ](http://www.jboss.org/hornetq).

RabbitMQ does not provide such functionality and it does for good reasons. RabbitMQ is built for being extremely robust and to perform like hell at the same time. The transactional behavior that you describe is only achievable with the cost of reasonable performance loss (especially if you want to keep outstanding robustness).

With RabbitMQ, one way to assure that a message was consumed successfully, is indeed to publish an answer message on the consumer side that is then consumed by the original publisher. This can be achieved through [RabbitMQ's RPC procedure calls](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html) which might help you to get a clean solution for your problem setting.

If the (original) publisher crashes before all answers could be received, you can assume that all outstanding answers are still queued on the broker. So you would have to build your publisher in a way that it is capable to resume with processing those left messages. This might turn out to be none-trivial.

**Finally, I recommend the following solution:** Design your producing component in a way that you can consume the answers with one or more dedicated answer consumers that are separated from the origin publisher.

Benefits of this solution are:

1. the origin publisher can finish its task independent of consumer success
2. the origin publisher is independent of consumer availability and speed
3. the origin publisher implementation is far less complex
4. in a crash scenario, the answer consumer can resume with processing answers

**Now to a more general point:** One of the major benefits of messaging is the decoupling of application components by the broker. In AMQP, this is achieved with exchanges and bindings that allow you to move message distribution logic from your application to a central point of configuration.

If you add RPC-style calls to your clients, then your components are most likely closely coupled again, meaning that the publishing component fails if one of the consuming components fails / is not available / too slow. This is exactly what you will want to avoid. Otherwise, why would you have split the components then?

My recommendation is that you design your application in a way that publishers can complete their tasks independent of the success of consumers wherever possible. Back-channels should be an exceptional case and be implemented in the described not-so coupled way.

Comment: Thanks, Chris. Yes, this is what've done: each consumer sends its own message "back" -- to a separate queue, which was specified by the original publisher. It works -- and, perhaps, better than using RPCs would, because the aggregator of these confirmations does not have to be online at the same time as the confirming consumer. But the aggregator's code reimplements some of the functionality (such as reboot-tolerance) already found in the broker and I was hoping to leverage the latter for the purpose...